# why adminer.css is not reflecting even after restart the apache?

Tags: linux, database, configuration, lamp, adminer

I installed adminer in Ubuntu 22.10 using CLI and it was working successfully in `http://localhost/adminer`. Now I want to change the theme. Adminer file location `(usr/share/adminer)`. Here I added adminer.css file from [here](https://github.com/vrana/adminer/blob/master/designs/dracula/adminer.css) and it was not working in my web browser.

I tried these command for restart the web sever

`sudo service apache2 reload` 
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Also , I cleared the caches as well but it was not reflecting in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. What I did is, I removed the default adminer installation using `apt remove adminer -y`. Then I downloaded the newest version of adminer from https://www.adminer.org/ and placed the .php file into my default web folder (located at `/var/www/html`) such as the adminer.css file I have downloaded.

Comment: But, I think we need to move `adminer.css` to adminer configuation folder.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian 12 here.  The `adminer` package installs the initial config in `/etc/adminer` which is what `httpd` is redirected to access when `/adminer` is accessed in your web server from the web browser.  It confused me for a while too with the documentation available, and also `httpd` redirects don't work like symbolic links on the file system, so accessing `/adminer/adminer.php` throws a 404 error.

The single `conf.php` in `/etc/adminer` does all the magic from there and includes `/usr/share/adminer` for processing.  In fact, that's the only file after `/adminer/` that can be accessed directly from your web browser.  Due to all this, from your browser's perspective, the `adminer.php` is technically in the same place as the `conf.php`.

#### Therefore, the correct place for `adminer.css` is in `/etc/adminer`.  No need to restart any services or clear any caches, just refresh your web page and voila! The new theme/design will take effect.

This also makes sense if you consider packaging and file hierarchy conventions: the end user/administrator should normally not need to make edits to `/usr/share` data, for example, as any changes risk getting overwritten when packages are updated.